# Convert an Oracle pagination query into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, pagination

How can I convert this pagination query to be compatible with MySQL:

```
'SELECT *
      FROM ( select p.*, ROWNUM rnum
      FROM ( select * from employees ) p
      WHERE ROWNUM <= '.(($current_page)*$perpage).' ) where ROWNUM  > '.(($current_page -1)*$perpage)';
```

This query is used inside a PHP script and works without problems.

Comment: but why the down vote .. this is unfair

Comment: I haven't downvoted but the tool tip says _"This question does not show any research effort..."_. There are over 1,000 questions on Stack Overflow that already deal with pagination in MySQL... I'd guess that people are downvoting because you haven't looked at any of them.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Limit in mysql

```
 limit ($current_page -1)*$perpage , ($current_page)*$perpage
```

Comment: can you write the complete query please